# What do Line2D objects returned by seaborn.lineplot with hue represent?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 

# generate data
rng = np.random.default_rng(12)

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 50)
y1, y2 = np.sin(x[:25]), np.cos(x[25:])
cat = rng.choice(["a", "b", "c"], 50)

data = pd.DataFrame({"x": x , "y" : y1.tolist() + y2.tolist(), "cat": cat})

# generate figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5), ncols=2)
g0 = sns.lineplot(x="x", y="y", data=data, hue='cat', ls="--", ax=ax[0])
g1 = sns.lineplot(x="x", y="y", data=data, hue='cat', ls="--", ax=ax[1])

g1.get_lines()[0].set_color('black')

print(ax[0].get_lines())

for line in ax[0].get_lines():
    print(line.get_label())

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

This returns a list:

```
<a list of 6 Line2D objects>
```

of which the first three objects are the coloured dotted lines in the left subplot in the figure, confirmed by changing the color of one of these lines in the right subplot.

[image]

But I am unable to understand what the last three Line2D objects are in the list `ax[0].get_lines()`.

If I try to access the labels of the Line2D objects using

```
[line.get_label() for line in ax[0].get_lines()]
```

it gives `['_child0', '_child1', '_child2', 'b', 'a', 'c']`.

But the last three Line2D objects in the list don't behave like an usual Line2D object since

1. `ax[0].get_lines()[-1].set_lw(0.2)` did not change anything perceivable in the figure.
2. I expected `ax[0].get_lines()[-1].remove()`
   would remove green colored legend line in the left subplot, but it had no effect.

So, what do the last three Line2D objects in the list `ax[0].get_lines()`, which do not have the string `_child` in their labels, represent?

Generated with matplotlib (v3.5.1) and seaborn (v0.11.2).

Comment: Finally, a decent seaborn question with a complete [mre]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These are dummy lines used to create the legend.  Seaborn's legends can be quite complex, due to the many options. You might want to check out [this github issue](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2231) to get an idea about Seaborn trying to create more elaborate legends than what matplotlib currently allows.

If you change the properties of these dummy lines after the legend has been created, you won't see an effect. However, creating the legend again afterwards will show the change.

```py
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

# generate data
rng = np.random.default_rng(12)

x = np.linspace(0, np.pi, 50)
y1, y2 = np.sin(x[:25]), np.cos(x[25:])
x = np.round(x / 2, 1) * 2
cat = rng.choice(["a", "b", "c"], 50)

data = pd.DataFrame({"x": x, "y": y1.tolist() + y2.tolist(), "cat": cat})

# generate figure
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(8, 5), ncols=2)
g0 = sns.lineplot(x="x", y="y", data=data, hue='cat', ls="--", ax=ax[0])
g1 = sns.lineplot(x="x", y="y", data=data, hue='cat', ls="--", ax=ax[1])

g1.get_lines()[0].set_color('black')
g1.get_lines()[3].set_color('purple')
g1.get_lines()[3].set_linewidth(5)
g1.legend()  # create the legend again

plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: the dummy line objects are used for the legend]

PS: If you just want to change the legend symbols (called "handles" in matplotlib), you can change them directly, e.g.:

```py
for h in g1.legend_.legendHandles:
     h.set_linestyle("--")
```

The reason that, in this example, the legend doesn't automatically apply the linestyle, is that the `ls=` parameter gets sent directly to matplotlib for drawing the lines, but not to the code to create seaborn's legend. In a future seaborn version, this will probably be tackled. As seaborn allows many combinations of options, it is non-trivial to get this working satisfactory for all those combinations. See also [open issue 2861](https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/2861).

Comment: Nice explanation, though if you want to do post-hoc artist updates it's probably better to grab the artists _from_ the legend rather than the ones that are used to populate it when it gets (re)created.

Comment: Sir JohanC, I have to ask an one word question from you about Matplotlib is **Name the parameter for getting legends in the graph?**

Comment: Sir I am talking about Matplotlib not Seaborn.

Comment: Well, seaborn is a layer around matplotlib. Check out e.g. matplotlib's [legend guide](https://matplotlib.org/stable/tutorials/intermediate/legend_guide.html) for additional information. The code to create a matplotlib legend is `ax.legend()`.  I now added some code to update the legend handles directly.